# GTKmm + pipe() not working

Tags: c++, linux, pipeline, gtkmm

I have this code:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void send_msg(Gtk::Entry* entry, int* fd);
Glib::ustring* receive_msg(int* fd);
bool handle_msg(Gtk::Label* lbl, int* fd);




int main()
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    Gtk::Main gtkmain;
    Gtk::Window* win;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder;

    if (pid > 0)
    {
        close(fd[1]);

        builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("parent.glade");
        builder->get_widget("parentwin", win);

        Gtk::Label* lbl;
        builder->get_widget("label", lbl);
        sigc::slot<bool> timer = sigc::bind(sigc::ptr_fun(&handle_msg), lbl, fd);
        Glib::signal_timeout().connect(timer, 1000);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd[0]);

        builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("child.glade");
        builder->get_widget("childwin", win);

        Gtk::Button* send;
        Gtk::Entry* txt;
        builder->get_widget("send", send);
        builder->get_widget("msg", txt);
        send->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::bind(sigc::ptr_fun(&send_msg), txt, fd));
    }

    Gtk::Main::run(*win);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}







void send_msg(Gtk::Entry* entry, int* fd)
{
    Glib::ustring msg = entry->get_text();
    const char* c_msg = msg.c_str();

    int i = 0;
    char* c = new char(0);

    while (*c = c_msg[i++])
    {
        write(fd[1], c, 1);
    }
}



Glib::ustring* receive_msg(int* fd)
{
    Glib::ustring* msg = new Glib::ustring;
    char* c = new char(0);

    do
    {
        read(fd[0], c, 1);
        msg->append(c);
    } while (*c);

    return msg;
}



bool handle_msg(Gtk::Label* lbl, int* fd)
{
    Glib::ustring* msg;
    msg = receive_msg(fd);
    lbl->set_text(*msg);
    // delete msg;
    return true;
}
```

and it's purpose is this:
The whole program works similar to a chat program, just not intended for that. The `child` process brings up a window with an Entry and a Button in it, to send the contents of Entry using a low level code that uses `write()` function, and the parent brings up a window with just a Label in it to display the data received at low level with `read()`.

The exact functionality that I'm after I could achieve without gtkmm, but even when I write the `read()` and `write()` codes right before gtkmm parts under `close()` to test the functionality of read/write as a test to bypass function calls, it still won't work.

The only possibility I can think of, is an incompatibility between `unistd.h` and `gtkmm.h`.

(and also I know the code is a bunch of dirt in writing, to some extent, but its a practice, forget that! ;-) )

Thanks so much for your helps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipe-management code is wrong. You're supposed to `pipe()` *before* you `fork()`, to make sure both file descriptors are inherited into the child process. Read up on the documentation of these functions.

[Here](http://mij.oltrelinux.com/devel/unixprg/#ipc__pipes) is a quite dense tutorial on Unix programming, it's clearly visible that `pipe()` is more or less the first call made, before launching the child process.

Comment: OH MY ...
I was just editing the code! But thanks so much anyway!